# IIS serves ASPX but not ASMX

Tags: asp.net, iis, asmx

Deployed an ASP.NET webforms application to IIS 6.0 64-bit server. Some associated DLLs are only available in 32-bit so I enabled 32-bit applications following [these](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/894435) instructions. At first I was not able to view ASPX pages but I had forgotten to Allow the ASP.NET Web Service Extension. Sorted!

Recent testing has shown that a 404 is received when requesting ASMX web service files. From the IIS log the status code is:

> 404 0 2

Anyone have any ideas? I anticipate this being something silly like all 404s.

**UPDATE 1**

Not sure if this is related but the same error code is received when requesting PNG files. No problem serving JPG or GIF from the same folder... **what!!!???** It is worth noting that if I change the extension of the image to JPG then it can be requested.

**UPDATE 2**

See answer below.

Comment: Are the ASMX web services built using the same .NET Framework release as the ASPX pages?

Comment: @Simen S - The ASMX and ASPX are in the same project.

Comment: The .png issue could be a registry problem - make sure you've got a key .png under HKLM\Software\Classes which has a "Content Type" value. (It sohuld be "image/png" but that ought not matter.) That said, I don't think this should break the .asmx, and I can't imagine Server 2003 shipped without a .png content type in the registry.

Comment: @Rup - Just checked the Registry and the key does exist. This is driving me bananas!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay found the problem.

C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\urlscan\UrlScan.ini did not have the PNG and ASMX extensions specified in the AllowExtensions list.

A nice quirk in our IIS server build!

Answer (score 2):

Have you made sure that for .asmx file types, the handler is mapped to asp.net dll and that "check if file exists" is unticked within IIS?

Comment: +1 for the handler check, but why would he need to untick 'check if file exists'? That's usually just for MVC or routing-based apps - normally ASMX files do exist. If you want to correct the handler then it's probably best to run `aspnet_regiis`

Comment: I have checked the mappings and both ASPX and ASMX are pointing to the same aspnet_isapi.dll.

Comment: Actually .asmx files usually gets compiled into the binaries and don't actually exist on the disk. The only other thing I can think of is something in the web.config conflicting with the way IIS is handling the asmx files. Try putting a test handler for asmx files in place that simply writes to an event log whenever an asmx file is requested. That will tell you if IIS is routing the calls properly to begin with or not.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed connection pool to "Classic" from integtrated and it started working for me